# Why is the absolutely positioned element extending the parent element's height

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Consider this code snippet. i have absolutely positioned the .slideup div relative to the body.

Now I know that absolutely positioned elements are cut from the normal flow of content and treated as if they do not exist in the parent element.

But here the .slideup div is extending the parent(body) element's height even though max-height is set to 100vh.

What I am basically trying to do is make the message slide up on the screen from below, but this code is make it visible to the user when scrolled down, which i don't wish to happen.

Why is this happening and how can i fix this??

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; */
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 110%;
}


/************************************/
/* SLIDER */
/************************************/

.slideup {
  /* display: none; */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: .8rem .8rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s bottom ease;
}

.slideup.show {
  bottom: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hangman</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--  -->

  <div class="slideup show">
    <div class="notification">You have already entered this letter!</div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not extending the body. Add border to the body to see. You simply triggered the overflow of the screen since you have elements outside of the view

Comment: overflow: hidden; on the body will fix this

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for pointing that out!! But why doesn't this behavior when i set left or right property to -100%. why can't i scroll to the left/right in that case?

Comment: if you set right you will also have scroll. You won't have scroll on the left and on the top only because scroll work in only one direction based on the text direction (either top or bottom AND either left or right)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @TemaniAfif, this problem is fixed by adding a simple `overflow: hidden` property to body element.

The absolutely positioned div .slideup doesn't extend the parent's height but rather overflows it. This behavior can also be verified by adding a border to body and also by adding right or bottom property to the .slideup div.